# Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled while running protractor automation scripts

Tags: google-chrome, opengl-es, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

**I'm a newbie here .**

**My protractor automation scripts are failing Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled**

Below is the error

"DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60154/devtools/browser/784192ee-bb6e-40c7-8722-a752e25d1636

Started

[15180:23164:0525/154437.543:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:44:37.543] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: **A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)**

[15180:23164:0525/154437.546:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:44:37.547] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

[15180:23164:0525/154437.547:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:44:37.548] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

**[12120:18212:0525/154512.227:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(426)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled**

**This is my Graphic feature status**

Canvas: Hardware accelerated

Compositing: Hardware accelerated

Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled

Out-of-process Rasterization: Hardware accelerated

OpenGL: Enabled

Rasterization: Hardware accelerated

Skia Renderer: Enabled

Video Decode: Hardware accelerated

Vulkan: Disabled

WebGL: Hardware accelerated

WebGL2: Hardware accelerated

I tried to find solution from many days but no luck . Can anyone please help me explain me in detail how to fix this issue

**This is my details of chrome**

Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)

Revision e3cd97fc771b893b7fd1879196d1215b622c2bed-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#1429}

OS Windows 10 OS Version 1903 (Build 18362.1256)

JavaScript V8 9.0.257.29

User Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36

Command Line "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --enable-webgl-draft-extensions --ignore-gpu-blocklist --flag-switches-end --origin-trial-disabled-features=SecurePaymentConfirmation

**Any help is highly appreciated**